# Firebase assistant does not act similar to google instruction

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I used Firebase assistant from android studio tools to import firebase messaging into my android app. According to google instruction (firebase console > project setting), to import firebase manually, I had to generate **google-sevices.json** file which contains configuration details and put it in project tree. But using firebase assistant, there is no json file added to the tree however this tools found the project and says that connected to it.

Should I add **google-sevices.json** manually or assistant tool resolves it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which tree are you looking at? The json is added automatically under the "Project Files" tree if you are using the Android Studio Firebase tools, abide the tools are a little outdated.

[image]

Comment: before using firebase tool, I have imported my project from eclipse and the parent app folder has 4 subfolders manifest,java,assets and res. non of them contain `google-services.json.

Comment: Ok . I found it bu changing view from android view to project view. Thank you.